# Insert multiple rows with different values from a select

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables `Projects` and `ProjectFields`. I am trying to populate one with values from another plus some other values, this way:

```
INSERT INTO "ProjectFields" ("projectId", name, type, "isDefault")
      (SELECT "projectId", 'Notes', 'textarea', true FROM "Projects"), -- creates one field called 'Notes' for every project.
      (SELECT "projectId", 'Bio', 'textarea', true FROM "Projects"), -- creates one field called 'Bio' for every project.
      (SELECT "projectId", 'Photo', 'text', true FROM "Projects"); -- creates one field called 'Photo' for every project.
```

The idea is that every project must have three referenced fields in the `ProjectFields` table. I know that the code above doesn't work, is there any way to do this using `PostgreSQL` ?

If you have a better idea please tell me, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there! Just use [UNION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html) and *voilá*:

```
INSERT INTO "ProjectFields" ("projectId", name, type, "isDefault")
      SELECT "projectId", 'Notes', 'textarea', true FROM "Projects"
        UNION ALL
      SELECT "projectId", 'Bio', 'textarea', true FROM "Projects"
        UNION ALL
      SELECT "projectId", 'Photo', 'text', true FROM "Projects";

--As you asked, using only one SELECT on Projects (but using a CTE)
--But I didn't recommend this solution, why increase complexity of a query just to avoid the 3 SELECTS?
INSERT INTO "ProjectFields" ("projectId", name, "isDefault")
    WITH tmp (proj_id, field_name, is_default) AS (     
        SELECT "projectId", UNNEST(ARRAY['Notes','Bio', 'Photo']), true FROM "Projects"
    )
    SELECT proj_id, field_name, CASE field_name WHEN 'Notes' THEN 'textarea' WHEN 'Bio' THEN 'textarea' ELSE 'text' END,is_default FROM tmp;

--Or perhaps in a more cleaner way as stated by @Marth:
INSERT INTO "ProjectFields" ("projectId", name, "isDefault")
    SELECT * FROM projects, (VALUES ('notes', 'textarea'), ('bio', 'textarea'), ('Photo', 'text')) AS t(name, "type");
```

Comment: Is there a way to do only one select instead of three? thank you one more time @michel.milezzi.

Comment: Yes, but IMHO not worth it. See my updated answer. Regards!

Comment: @michel.milezzi: Your "1-SELECT" solution is a bit over-complicated, you could do `select ... from project, (values ('notes', 'textarea'), ('bio', 'text')) as t(name, "type")`. But yes, using `UNION ALL` is, I believe, the most common solution (and the easiest/most readable too).

Comment: @RafaelBerro: Purely out of curiosity, why are you looking for a "single select" way to do this?

Comment: @Marth you're right, I've updated my answer pointing it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers, @Marth I don't want to add a subquery every time I add a new field type, does it makes sense?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but with tens of thousands of rows. The 1-SELECT solutions are great.